# Android Studio Send Message Multiple Strings in Message

Tags: java, android, string, sendmessage

I am trying to send a message with three variables (Strings) but only with two I managed.

example:

String phone = "123456789";

String **message1** = "Hello I am Paul my birthday is ";

String **message2** = date;

String **message3** = time;

SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phone, null, **message1+message2+message3**, null,null);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect these three methods like "Hello I am Paul my birthday isDateTime",
You can Use StringBuilder:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(message1);
    sb.append(message2);
    sb.append(message3);
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phone, null, sb.toString(), null,null);
```